# How can I update my date and time without wifi access?

Tags: kindle-fire

I've got a Fire 7 whose battery died completely and the Date/Time is now 8+ years off (Dec 31, 2009). Our WiFi network requires agreeing to our internet policy, however since the time/date are wrong I can't get far enough to connect to the internet. I can't seem to find a way to update the time/date manually (it's set to connect to the internet to update automatically). I've got a bit of a Catch-22 here. Is there any way I can update the date and time without connecting to the internet?